# Does the sequence $(Z_n)$ converge or diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $(c_n)$ be a real and strictly monotone sequence that converges to a limit $c > 1$.
Let's assume that $c_n > 1$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Let's $\beta$ be a real constant such that $\beta \neq r \pi$ where $r \in \mathbb{Q}$.
Let's define the sequence $z_n$ such that for each $n$:
\begin{eqnarray} z_n = \frac{\tan(\beta n) + c}{\tan(\beta n) + c_n} \end{eqnarray}
Where $\tan$ is the trigonometric tangent function.
Does the sequence $(z_n)$ converge or diverge?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Notice that $\tan(\beta n)$ could also be equal to $-c_n$ for infinitely many $n$, so $z_n$ may not even be defined...

Comment: @Exodd Using standard results about $\alpha n$ mod 1 we can see that no matter what $tan(\beta n)$ must come arbitrarily close to $-c$ infinitley often. This at least shows potential issues no matter what, however we can also use it to choose $c_n$ so that $tan(\beta n)=-c_n$ infinitely often.

Comment: Let's assume that $(c_n)$ is a strictly decreasing sequence. I think the sequence $(z_n)$ diverges because the terms $tan(\beta n) + c$ and $tan(\beta n) + c_n$ can have different signs for certain $n$ when $\tan(\beta n)$ is close enough to $c$.

Comment: again, even if you take them decreasing, $\tan(\beta n) = -c_n$ is still a possibility, so $z_n$ are not well defined

Comment: I agree with you. But We can assume that $c_n \neq - \tan (\beta n) $ for each $n$, and try to (dis) prove the convergence.

Comment: You can easily choose a decreasing $c_n\to c$ such that $tan(\beta n) + c_n = (tan(\beta n) + c)/n$ infinitely often, but also $tan(\beta n) + c_n = (tan(\beta n) + c)$ infinitely often too, so that there is no convergence or divergence to infinity at all

Comment: Your first choice of $c_n$ clashes with the condition $ c_n > 1$ for each $n$. While the function tangent is not always positive. So we need to restrict it to only positive terms. The second choice of $c_n$ clashes with the strict monotonocity of $c_n$.

Comment: not at at all to both. You missed the 'infinitely often'

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Matthieu S we have an example of $c_n$ where $z_n$ converges to 1. In case we have $\tan(\beta n) + c \neq 0$ for each $n$ (or from a certain $n_0$) we can define the following $c_n$: \begin{eqnarray} c_n = c + \frac{  \min_{1 \leq i \leq n} ( \left| \tan(\beta i ) + c \right|  )  }{n} \end{eqnarray} In this case we have $z_n$ as follows: \begin{eqnarray}  z_n = 1 - \frac{1}{  1 + n   \frac{ \tan(\beta n ) + c  }{ \min_{1 \leq i \leq n} ( \left| \tan(\beta i ) + c \right|  )    }    }   \end{eqnarray}

And since \begin{eqnarray} \left| \frac{ \tan(\beta n ) + c  }{ \min_{1 \leq i \leq n} ( \left| \tan(\beta i ) + c \right|  )}  \right| \geq  1 \end{eqnarray}

then \begin{eqnarray} \left| 1 + n \frac{ \tan(\beta n ) + c  }{ \min_{1 \leq i \leq n} ( \left| \tan(\beta i ) + c \right|  )}  \right| \geq  n - 1 \end{eqnarray}
And therefore $(z_n)$ converges to $1$.
As a conclusion, the sequence $(z_n)$ diverges (most of the time) and there are (many) examples of $(c_n)$ where $(z_n)$ converges like the example above.